# Quantifiable statements question, is the statement true or false?!

Tags: quantifiers

The given quantified statement is:

$\forall p \in \P_3, \forall q \in \P_3, p-q \in \P_3.$

($\P_3$ stands for "third degree polynomial")

The question asks to state if the original is true or false. I negated the statement to be:  $\exists p \in \P_3, \exists q \in \P_3, p-q \in \P_3.$ I found the negation to be false, and the original to be true. Can I get a confirmation? I am not able to think of any counter examples, making me believe that the original is true. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- The first statement is a false statement.
- Strategy to find counter example: Well, to change the degree, make sure the leading coefficients of the two polynomials $p$ and $q$ are the same, hence the leading term will be eliminated.
- Secondly, you negated the statement wrongly, the negation should be $$\exists p \in P_3, \exists q \in P_3, p-q \notin P_3.$$
- The statement "$\exists p \in P_3, \exists q \in P_3, p-q \in P_3$"  is true. Prove this by finding an example.

Answer (score 0):

The original statement is false

Use $p=4x^3 + 2x^2 +6x -2$ and $q=4x^3$ for a simple example (there are plenty more)

Comment: Ah I see, thank you! What about if it was deg(p-q) $\in P_3$??

Comment: That statement wouldn't really make sense since deg(p-q) returns a number, which isn't a polynomial of degree 3. Therefore that statement would also be false.

Comment: What you could say is $\text{deg}(p-q) \le 3$. This is a true statement